# My multi-threaded application won't loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create a program that will run until the user stops it. It focuses on Santa's workshop where I have Santa, nine Reindeer and eleven elves. Eleven elves must create 100 toys (with a 5% chance to fail, in which case Santa helps) and the nine reindeer must return from holiday. When both events happen Santa delivers the toys. After that the nine reindeer go on holiday and the elves must create 100 more toys. Here is my code:

`main.java`

```
public class Main {

    private static Santa santa;
    public Semaphore elfSemaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    public Semaphore reindeerSemaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    public volatile int toyList = 100;
    public volatile int reindeersOnHoliday = 9;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Main main = new Main();

        santa = new Santa(main);


        Reindeer dasher = new Reindeer("Dasher", main);
        Reindeer dancer = new Reindeer("Dancer", main);
        Reindeer prancer = new Reindeer("Prancer", main);
        Reindeer vixen = new Reindeer("Vixen", main);
        Reindeer comet = new Reindeer("Comet", main);
        Reindeer cupid = new Reindeer("Cupid", main);
        Reindeer dunder = new Reindeer("Dunder", main);
        Reindeer blitzen = new Reindeer("Blitzen", main);
        Reindeer rudolph = new Reindeer("Rudolph", main);

        Elf elfOne = new Elf("Jim", main);
        Elf elfTwo = new Elf("John", main);
        Elf elfThree = new Elf("Eamonn", main);
        Elf elfFour = new Elf("Eoin", main);
        Elf elfFive = new Elf("Ronan", main);
        Elf elfSix = new Elf("Seamus", main);
        Elf elfSeven = new Elf("Rebecca", main);
        Elf elfEight = new Elf("Orla", main);
        Elf elfNine = new Elf("Tina", main);
        Elf elfTen = new Elf("Filly", main);
        Elf elfEleven = new Elf("Jess", main);

        santa.start();

        dasher.start();
        dancer.start();
        prancer.start();
        vixen.start();
        comet.start();
        cupid.start();
        dunder.start();
        blitzen.start();
        rudolph.start();

        elfOne.start();
        elfTwo.start();
        elfThree.start();
        elfFour.start();
        elfFive.start();
        elfSix.start();
        elfSeven.start();
        elfEight.start();
        elfNine.start();
        elfTen.start();
        elfEleven.start();

    }

    public void wakeSanta(String reason) throws InterruptedException {
        santa.setReasonForWake(reason);

    }

}
```

`elf.java`

```
public class Elf extends Thread{

    Random rng = new Random();
    String name;
    Main main;

    public Elf(String name, Main main){
        this.name = name;
        this.main = main;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
                try {
                    makeToy();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }

    private void makeToy() throws InterruptedException{
        main.elfSemaphore.acquire();
        if (main.getToyList() != 0){
            if(rng.nextInt(99) <= 4){
                System.out.println(name + " failed in making a toy! They went to Santa for help.");
                main.wakeSanta("problem");
            }else{
                main.setToyList(main.getToyList() - 1);
                System.out.println(name + " created a toy! Toys remaining: " + main.getToyList());
            }
        } else {
            main.wakeSanta("toys");
        }
        main.elfSemaphore.release();
    }

}
```

`reindeer.java`

```
public class Reindeer extends Thread {

    String name;
    boolean onHoliday;
    Main main;

    public Reindeer(String name, Main main){
        this.name = name;
        this.onHoliday = true;
        this.main = main;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            if(onHoliday){
                try {
                    returnFromHoliday();
                    if(name.equals("Rudolph") && main.getReindeersOnHoliday() == 0){
                        main.wakeSanta("reindeers");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                if (main.getReindeersOnHoliday() == 9){
                    onHoliday = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void returnFromHoliday() throws InterruptedException {
        onHoliday = false;
        System.out.println(name + " says: I'm back from holiday!");
        main.reindeerSemaphore.acquire();
        main.setReindeersOnHoliday(main.getReindeersOnHoliday() - 1);
        main.reindeerSemaphore.release();

    }

}
```

`santa.java`

```
public class Santa extends Thread {

    Main main;
    private boolean isSleeping = true;
    private String reasonForWake = "";

    public Santa(Main main){
        this.main = main;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            if(!isSleeping){
                if(reasonForWake.equals("reindeer")){
                    if(main.getToyList() == 0){
                        System.out.println("*****************************\nTime for Santa to deliver presents!\n*****************************");
                        deliverPresents();
                    } else{
                        isSleeping = true;
                    }
                } else if (reasonForWake.equals("problem")){
                    try {
                        main.elfSemaphore.acquire();
                        main.setToyList(main.getToyList() - 1);
                        System.out.println("Santa has helped an elf fix a problem. Toys left: " + main.getToyList());
                        isSleeping = true;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        main.elfSemaphore.release();
                    }
                } else { //toys
                    if(main.getReindeersOnHoliday() == 0){
                        System.out.println("*****************************\nTime for Santa to deliver presents!\n*****************************");
                        deliverPresents();
                    }
                    else {
                        isSleeping = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setReasonForWake(String reasonForWake) {
        isSleeping = false;
        this.reasonForWake = reasonForWake;
    }

    private void deliverPresents(){
        isSleeping = true;
        main.setReindeersOnHoliday(9);
        main.setToyList(100);
    }
}
```

It works for one year but it seems to get stuck in the `run()` of `santa.java` and never actually delivers the toys meaning it never loops. I think the code in main, elf and reindeer is pretty rock solid but I'm not sure about the Santa. Can anyone provide insight into how I can make it loop reliably?

Comment: I'm thinking that `isSleeping` should be `volatile`...BUT, it would actually be better to have a queue of some kind, which lists all the problems (so the fat man can deal with ALL the problems in the queue) and use a monitor lock instead...while the queue is empty, Santa gets a nap, while it's not, he has to deal with the problems...

Comment: volatile isn't enough, the whole `if(!isSleeping){ ... isSleeping = true)` block needs to be handled atomic or `setReasonForWake` can set sleeping to false, but get immediately overwritten. A queue is probably the only sane way out because threads are locked while they can wake santa otherwise,.